# Collect jars into a tar without directory

Tags: bash, find, tar

I have a large project that creates a large number of jars in a path similar to `project/subproject/target/subproject.jar`. I want to make a command to collect all the jars into one compressed tar, but without the directories. The command I have come up with so far is: `find project -name \*.jar -exec tar -rvf Collectors.tar.gz -C $(dirname {}) $(basename {}) \;` but this isn't quite working as I am intending, the directories are still there.

Does anyone have any ideas for how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is quite close, but the problem is that Bash is executing `$(dirname {})` and `$(basename {})` *before* executing `find`; so your command expands to this:

```
find project -name \*.jar -exec tar -rvf Collectors.tar.gz -C . {} \;
```

where the `-C .` is a no-op and the `{}` just expands to the full relative directory+filename.

One general-purpose way to fix this sort of thing is to wrap up the argument to `-exec` in a Bash one-liner, so you invoke Bash for each individual file, and let it execute the `dirname` and `basename` at the right time:

```
find project -name \*.jar -exec bash -c 'tar -rvf Collectors.tar.gz -C "$(dirname "$1")" "$(basename "$1")"' '' '{}' \;
```

In your specific case, however, I'd point you to `find`'s `-execdir` action, which is the same as `-exec` except that it `cd`'s into the file's directory first. So you can simply write:

```
find project -name '*.jar' -execdir tar -rvf "$PWD/Collectors.tar.gz" '{}' \;
```

(Note that `$PWD` part, which is to make sure that you write to the `Collectors.tar.gz` in the *current* directory, rather than in the directory that `find -execdir` will `cd` into.)

Comment: This is closer, but creates multiple tars. One in each directory. I need one tar with all the jars.

Comment: Whoops, ha, duh, will fix, sorry.